# Filing in linked list c++

Tags: c++, linked-list, file-handling

I'm trying to do filing through linked list. What i want to do is place every word in my text file on a new node but this program is placing all the words on a single node. For e.g if my text file has a line ***"my name is ahsan"*** in it then its output should be:

my

name

is

ahsan

while my program is printing this line as it is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include<fstream>
using namespace std;

class node
{
public:
string data;
node*next;
};

class mylist
{ 
public:
node*head;
mylist()
{
    head=NULL;
}
void insertion(string item)
{
    node* temp= new node;
    temp->data=item;
    temp->next=NULL;
    temp->next=head;
    head=temp;
}
void print()
{
    node*ptr;
    if(head==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"List empty :"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        ptr=head;
        while(ptr!=NULL)
        {
            cout<<ptr->data<<endl<<endl;
            ptr=ptr->next;
        }
    }
 }
 };

int main()
{
ofstream myfile;
ifstream infile;
string mystring;
mylist l;

//  myfile.open ("ahsan.txt");
//  myfile << "Ahsan's first file.\n";
//  myfile.close();
string lol;
infile.open("ahsan.txt");
while(!infile.eof())
{
    getline(infile,lol);
    l.insertion(lol);
}

l.print();
infile.close();

}
```

Comment: And the question is? BTW - Perhaps using a debugger first would be quicker to set to get any answer

Comment: That what mistake im making due to which it couldn't copy the words to a new node everytime instead it copies all the words to the a single node.

Answer (score 2):

That because you use getline for that. getline read your text per line, not per word. Instead you can use your input stream to do that.

```
infile >> myString;
```

It will read per word, assuming you want to split it by space...

Comment: Thankyou for the answer it solved my problem but the linked list is being printed in reverse form now.

Comment: @AhsanAsif That's because you insert each node at the head of the list. You need to append to the tail of the list.

Comment: Yeah, as @JohnnyMopp say you insert them on head (basicaly it make your linkedlist insert at first rather than last.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyMopp i forgot that i was using insertion at head.